# Using Which with a symbol-based test

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a problem using `Which`. I am making a function in Mathematica where one of the arguments (`arg2`) is supposed to be a `Symbol` (either `None` or `Full`).
I want the output of the function to be dependent on `arg2` like this, but it doesn't work:

```
testFunction[arg1_,arg2_:None]:=Which[arg2==None,arg1*2,arg2==Full,arg1*3]
```

If `arg2` is `None` there seems to be no problem, but for `arg2` is `Full`, `testFunction` just returns itself.
When using reals or integers instead of symbols `None` and `Full`, `testFunction` functions properly.

Am I making a mistake using symbols in the tests? Or are there any other 'rules' I should be aware of when using `Which` and symbols together?

I already search this and other sites for an answer but couldn't find any. The Mathematica help files didn't provide an answer to me either. Everywhere I looked Which is not used witch symbols.

Comment: You can post future question on [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) to get better answers more quickly.  It's a very similar site which specializes in Mathematica.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to use `SameQ` (i.e. the operator `===`) instead of `Equal` (the operator `==`).

[`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Equal.html) is for Mathematical equality.  `a==b` does not evaluate, meaning Mathematica does not know if these variables have the same value or not.  `1==2` evaluates to `False` while `a==a` evaluates to `True`.

[`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SameQ.html) is for structural equality, and will always evaluate either to `True` or to `False`.  It will only evaluate to `True` if the expressions being compared are equal structurally.  It does not attempt to test mathematical equality, so e.g. `0 === 0.0` will give `False` as the two expressions are structurally different (one is an exact number, the other a machine precision one).

Here you need structural equality because you need `Full === None` to evaluate to `False` (while `Full == None` stays unevaluated).  Just use

```
testFunction[arg1_,arg2_:None]:=Which[arg2===None,arg1*2,arg2===Full,arg1*3]
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for.Strange that I didn't encounter this discrepancy before, or maybe i just forgot about it...

Answer (score 1):

While using `SameQ` is a solution, I think there are better ways to construct this.  `Switch` is the most direct replacement:

```
f[arg1_, arg2_: None] := Switch[arg2, None, arg1*2, Full, arg1*3]

f[7]
f[7, None]
f[7, Full]
```

> ```
> 14
> 14
> 21
> ```

Often it is best to avoid Which/Switch etc. and use patterns, e.g.:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[arg1_, Full] := arg1*3
f[arg1_, None | PatternSequence[]] := arg1*2

f[7]
f[7, None]
f[7, Full]
```

> ```
> 14
> 14
> 21
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr. Wizard.
Why is it best to avoid Which/Switch? Are they slower than patterns? Personally i think Which is a very neat way of doing things like this, patterns make the code (for me) less clear.

Comment: @Pater yes, often they are slower.  [Read this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2618/121) for an example.  Also, I personally find that patterns are easier to read after getting used to them, and they are ultimately more flexible and better integrated in *Mathematica*, so there are a variety of special tricks you cannot use with `Which`/`Switch`. (see `Default`, `Optional`, `OptionsPattern`, `OptionValue`, `UpSet`, etc. in the documentation)